# Bubble Sort code : Exception in main thread

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int nums[] = {9,8,4,5,6,7};
        int temp=0;

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<nums.length;j++){
                if(nums[j]>nums[j+1]){                    //swap
                    temp=nums[j];
                    nums[j]=nums[j+1];
                    nums[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){          //print array after sorting
            System.out.print(nums[i]+"-->");
        }
    }
}
```

I need the solution to be sorted in ascending order. However, it keeps throwing an error-->

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6 at Average.main(Average.java:21).

Answer (score 3):

that is because in the inner loop you iterate until for `j < nums.length` but then you access on `j+1` index `nums[j+1]`. Replace the inner loop with

```java
for (int j = 0; j < nums.length - 1; j++) {
...
```